# Setting "Definition Expression" to StreamLayer?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How to set "Definition Expression" to a StreamLayer where the data is not coming from an ArcGIS Server Stream?

I try with the following method `streamLayer.setDefinitionExpression("field='value'");` but doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean with "data is not coming from an AGS Stream"? Where is the data caming from?

Comment: @Katah The data is coming from an Socket, you can define a "socketUrl" (URL used to make the socket connection.)

Comment: if you test `streamLayer.getDefinitionExpression()` after set the Definition expresion, what are you getting?
I guess it is only working if the Data is coming from an AGS. If you check the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/streamlayer-amd.html#getdefinitionexpression), it says: 
_Gets the where property of the layer's filter. Only relevant when data for the layer is coming from an ArcGIS Server Stream Service._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `streamLayer.setDefinitionExpression("field='value'");` ArcGIS JS API will send a message to the server with the filter `{"filter":{"where":"field='value'"}}`, this is automatically handled by Stream Services and the next data you receive will be filtered.

If you have a custom server (Web socket Server) you need to receive the filter and apply to the stream you are sending to clients.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.